# What is this anime song called?

Tags: identify-this-song, japan

skip to 0:58 where they have the person laying down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The song is "Believe in Tomorrow" by Sunflower's Garden.

Comment: OMG THANKS SO MUCH I HEARD THAT SONG FROM THERE AND ALWAYS WANT TO KNOW if this was real life i would give you 20 dollars